# Get the currency of a locale

Tags: php, localization, currency

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the default currency from the PHP Intl ( ICU library )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325002/how-to-get-the-default-currency-from-the-php-intl-icu-library)

I am using the intl extension in php to deal with localizing the content and formatting things. Since I already know the locale such as en_US, is it possible to get the currency of the locale from PHP?

I should get $ or USD if locale is en_US and $ or AUD if locale is en_AU.

I need to get the 3-letter ISO 4217 currency code to pass into numberFormatter::Currency.

Thanks :)

Comment: I am using numberformatter::Currency from the intl extension to do the formatting, so this approach will not work.

Comment: Check out @Gordon 's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8325456/419

Answer (score 0):

The [`localeconv()`](http://php.net/localeconv) function will give you a number of useful facts about the current locale, including the international currency symbol (as `int_curr_symbol`).

If the locale you're interested in isn't set as the current locale, you'll have to temporarily switch to it using [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/setlocale).

Comment: This would be ideal, but setlocale is so inconsistent across systems that I would rather avoid it.

Comment: It's about the best you're going to get without hard-coding a table mapping locales to currency symbols, though. Many systems, including Linux, don't have any functions in libc to get data from a locale that isn't active.

Comment: If you're using a Framework, or have access to one, you might want to use their implementation which is system agnostic.