# How to get the default currency from the PHP Intl ( ICU library )

Tags: php, locale, currency, icu, intl

I use PHP, and like to know how I can get the default currency for a locale via the Internationalization extension (Wrapper for the ICU library)?

Below is a script that explains, what and why. 
I need something to replace the `getCurrCode()` function with.

```
$accepted_currencies = array('USD','EUR');
$locale = Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
if( ! empty($locale)){
    Locale::setDefault($locale);
    $currency = getCurrCode();
    if( ! in_array($currency, $accepted_currencies)){
        $currency = 'USD';
    }
}else{
    Locale::setDefault('en_US');
}

$fmt = new NumberFormatter( $locale, NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
$price = $fmt->formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, $currency);
```

I know, I could use `setlocale(LC_MONETARY, $locale);` but that means I have to install all the locale's on to Linux, and deal with the variation of the Linux distros. What would then be the point of using Intl at the first place?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Once you set the Locale to the NumberFormatter, you can fetch the Currency Code with

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('de_DE', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo $formatter->getTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE);

$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo $formatter->getTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE);

$formatter = new NumberFormatter('ja_JP', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo $formatter->getTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE);
```

The above would give EUR, USD and JPY.

Comment: In Bhutan, there are 2 currencies (BTN and INR) but your sample code is returning only one (BTN) :(

Comment: or for Cuba (es_CU), it only returns "CUP". Though in Cuba, there are two currencies i.e. "CUP" and "CUC"

Comment: @ObaidMaroof please refer to the ICU documentation on how the handle these cases.

Comment: For anyone who **only has the country code**, the NumberFormatter accepts English as a language for any country. So just use `en_` plus your country code.