# Is is possible to detect the best local currency with PHP without ICU?

Tags: php, internationalization, currency

I want to show the user a buy/sell form, and I would like their local currency to already be filled in so non-US customers don't have to change this each time they visit the page.

I was made hopeful seeing [How to get the default currency from the PHP Intl ( ICU library )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325002/how-to-get-the-default-currency-from-the-php-intl-icu-library), but the problem is that I can *only* use vanilla PHP (I don't have control over what's installed on the servers), and so don't have ICU available to me.

Instead, I looked to duplicates and tried `var_dump(localeconv());`, but that led to this useless array:

```
array(18) {
  ["decimal_point"]=>
  string(1) "."
  ["thousands_sep"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["int_curr_symbol"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["currency_symbol"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["mon_decimal_point"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["mon_thousands_sep"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["positive_sign"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["negative_sign"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["int_frac_digits"]=>
  int(127)
  ["frac_digits"]=>
  int(127)
  ["p_cs_precedes"]=>
  int(127)
  ["p_sep_by_space"]=>
  int(127)
  ["n_cs_precedes"]=>
  int(127)
  ["n_sep_by_space"]=>
  int(127)
  ["p_sign_posn"]=>
  int(127)
  ["n_sign_posn"]=>
  int(127)
  ["grouping"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["mon_grouping"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

So, given vanilla PHP failed me and I can't use libraries, **is this still possible?**

Answer (score 0):

If the locale you're interested in isn't set as the current locale, you'll have to temporarily switch to it using `setlocale().`

[setlocale — Set locale information](http://php.net/setlocale)